# How to open new chrome using 'window.open ' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, resize

I made a function that should copy current tab's url, and make a new chrome window, and paste it. It seems works well as I think, but 'window.open' function can not open default chrome browser. Even though i configure d 'toolbar, scrollbar' options, New window have not been generated with default chrome. How can I solve it?

Next two pictures are example. First one is pre state, next one is after state when function was just executed. back, forward, reload, button aren't generated, and other functions not visible on this picture as well.

[image: pre state]
[image: next state]

```
function currentNewWinndow () {
    var currentPage = window.location.href;
    window.close();
    var pop         = window.open( 
        currentPage,
        "_blank", 
        "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
        "top=0,left=window.screen.availWidth/2," +
        "window.screen.availWidth/2,window.screen.availHeight");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after raising this question, I finally found the issue that was put forward six years ago. And it hasn't been fixed yet. Here's the link
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82522

It seems that the team doesn't see this as a priority. So I think we can do nothing about it unless we contribute to chromium on our own.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this code. and

```
//Paste you url here 
   var win = window.open('http://your_url_goes_here.com/', '_blank');
    if (win) {
        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();
    } else {
        //Browser has blocked it
       alert('Please allow popups for this website');
    }
```

> Hope this will work for you, Good Luck